# JavaScript is not loaded site change with jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, django, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile website builded with Django as backend (should be irrelevant in this case). When i do page changes the JavaScript is not loaded on the next page. I have wrapped all the JavaScript inside following clause:

```
$("#mypage").on('pagecreate',  function() {
    var duration_minute = 1;
    $("#min_knob").val(duration_minute);
    {# $(function() { #}
        var minute_min = 0;
        var minute_max = duration_minute;
        var second_min = 0;
        var second_max = 60;

        $("#min_knob").knob({
            'min': minute_min,
            'max':minute_max,
            'readOnly':true,
            'thickness':0.2,
            'width': '100',
            'height': '100',
            'fgColor':'#34495e',
            draw: function () {
                 $(this.i).val(this.cv + 'm')
            },

        });

        $("#sek_knob").knob({
            'min': second_min,
            'max': second_max,
            'readOnly':true,
            'thickness':0.2,
            'width': '100',
            'height': '100',
            'fgColor':'#e67e22',
            draw: function () {
                 $(this.i).val(this.cv + 's')
            },
        });
});
```

If i open the page directly instead of changing pages the JavaScript loads flawlessly. Additional JavaScript files are added to the body, which has relevance to this problem.

```
    ...
    <script src="{% static "js/jquery.knob.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/jquery.ccountdown.js" %}"></script>
</body>
```

Im not sure if the reverse functions in Django do a great impact in the behavior of jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Are you using _Single Page Model_ or _Multi-Page Model_? If the first one and Ajax is enabled, add custom js inside `data-role=page` div.

Comment: @Omar, i may be using jQuery Mobile in a unorthodox way than it should. All my pages are separated in each its own HTML file, and not as the actual convention jQuery Mobile describes, which is either Single Page or Multi Page.. Is this bad practice? Although i prefer to keep it this way, but apparently its a issue. I tried to move the JS into the page div as you mentioned, but still the problem persists.

Comment: I replaced the ID of my div with `document` and the problem was solved.